# ToggleButton in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Is it possible to create a toggle button in C# WinForms? I know that you can use a CheckBox control and set it's Appearance property to "Button", but it doesn't look right. I want it to appear sunken, not flat, when pressed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the OnPaint and OnBackgroundPaint events and manually drawing the button exactly like I need it. It worked pretty well.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/794577/Windows-Forms-ToggleButton Here's such a code..

Comment: There might be an issue with themes.  Although that is probably safer than using Win32 interop calls.

Answer (score 174):

You can just use a `CheckBox` and set its appearance to `Button`:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
checkBox.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Comment: Use [archive.org link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140214234414/http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=797)

Answer (score 10):

Check FlatStyle property. Setting it to "System" makes the checkbox sunken in my environment.

Comment: That makes it flat when the box is unchecked however.

Comment: It's raised when unchecked and sunken when checked on my machine (Vista made to look like Win 2000 - Windows Classic theme).

Comment: You're right! I accidentally had it on Popup for the style. My bad.

Comment: If the buttons are to be mutually exclusive, you could do the same thing with RadioButton, also.

Answer (score 5):

You may also consider the ToolStripButton control if you don't mind hosting it in a ToolStripContainer. I think it can natively support pressed and unpressed states.

Answer (score 5):

thers is a simple way to create toggle button. I test it in vs2010. It's perfect.

ToolStripButton has a "Checked" property and a "CheckOnClik" property. You can use it to act as a toggle button

```
tbtnCross.CheckOnClick = true;
```

OR

```
    tbtnCross.CheckOnClick = false;
    tbtnCross.Click += new EventHandler(tbtnCross_Click);
    .....

    void tbtnCross_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripButton target = sender as ToolStripButton;
        target.Checked = !target.Checked;
    }
```

also, You can create toggle button list like this:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrToolView[0] = tbtnCross;
        arrToolView[1] = tbtnLongtitude;
        arrToolView[2] = tbtnTerrain;
        arrToolView[3] = tbtnResult;
        for (int i = 0; i<arrToolView.Length; i++)
        {
            arrToolView[i].CheckOnClick = false;
            arrToolView[i].Click += new EventHandler(tbtnView_Click);
        }
        InitTree();
    }

    void tbtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripButton target = sender as ToolStripButton;
        if (target.Checked) return;
        foreach (ToolStripButton btn in arrToolView)
        {
                btn.Checked = false;
                //btn.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }
        target.Checked = true;
        target.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

    }
```

Comment: It's not a control. How do you embed it on the GUI ?

Comment: You can use it in a toolstrip.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

Assuming you have System.Windows.Forms referenced.

```
var cbtnToggler = new CheckBox();
cbtnToggler.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
cbtnToggler.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
cbtnToggler.MinimumSize = new Size(75, 25); //To prevent shrinkage!
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is my simple codes I hope it can help you

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button2.Text == "ON")
        {
            panel_light.BackColor = Color.Yellow; //symbolizes light turned on

            button2.Text = "OFF";
        }

        else if (button2.Text == "OFF")
        {
            panel_light.BackColor = Color.Black; //symbolizes light turned off

            button2.Text = "ON";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This wasn't a bad answer, sure checkbox can apear as button, however checkboxes have limitations (one cannot set custom size independent of text size), so upvoting.

Comment: I liked this idea, but the visual placement of controls was unclear.  Played around  with symbols and even images to get the effect I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When my button's FlatStyle is set to system, it looks flat. And when it's set to popup, it only pops up when mouses over. Either is what I want.  I want it to look sunken when checked and raised when unchecked and no change while mousing over (the button is really a checkbox but the checkbox's appearance property is set to button).

I end up setting the FlatStyle to flat and wrote a new Paint event handler.

```
 private void checkbox_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox myCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
            Rectangle borderRectangle = myCheckbox.ClientRectangle;
            if (myCheckbox.Checked)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
                    Border3DStyle.Sunken);
            }
            else
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
                    Border3DStyle.Raised);
            }
        }
```

I give a similar answer to this question:
 [C# winforms button with solid border, like 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484556/c-sharp-winforms-button-with-solid-border-like-3d)
Sorry for double posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can always code your own button with custom graphics and a PictureBox, though it won't necessarily match the Windows theme of your users.

Answer (score 0):

use if command to check status and let operate as a toggle button

```
private void Protection_ON_OFF_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (FolderAddButton.Enabled == true)
            {
                FolderAddButton.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                FolderAddButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Siticone](https://www.siticoneframework.com/) I use it and I love it. It works exactly like a checkbox but is a toggle button. Its downside is a message box will come up every time you open Visual Studios so I just installed a tool that disables it. You can also look into Guana but I found that to have a few bugs :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31553841)

Answer (score -2):

Changing a CheckBox appearance to Button will give you difficulty in adjustments. You cannot change its dimensions because its size depends on the size of your text or image.

You can try this: (initialize the *count* variable first to 1 | int count = 1)

```
private void settingsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            settingsPanel.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            settingsPanel.Hide();
        }
    }
```

It's very simple but it works.

**Warning:** This will work well with buttons that are occasionally used (i.e. settings), the value of count in *int/long* may be overloaded when used more than it's capacity without closing the app's process. (Check data type ranges: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

**The Good News:** If you're running an app that is not intended for use 24/7 all-year round, I think this is helpful. Important thing is that when the app's process ended and you run it again, the *count* will reset to 1.

Comment: Why not just use a boolean flag? `currentlyVisible = !currentlyVisible; if(currentlyVisible) { settingsPanel.Show(); } ...`