# Toggle a button's text from "On" to "Off" when clicked (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was given a small task to simply make a button's text toggle "On" and "Off" when you clicked on it - it already starts with the text "Off" as it hasn't been pressed yet, but when you click it changes to "On". On each alternating click afterwards, the button's text would ideally keep changing from "On" to "Off". In my case I thought a simple boolean variable would be the solution as On and Off can be treated as True or False, but not to be...

Anyway here's the code for the button's handler I've got so far:

```
private: System::Void toggleButtonText_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
      static bool isOn = true;
      if(isOn == false)
      {
       toggleButtonText->Text = "Off";

      }
      else
      {
      toggleButtonText->Text = "On";
      }

}
```

As you can see, the name of the button is "toggleButtonText". In the InitializeComponent(void) method, this line enables the default text to "Off":

```
this->toggleButtonText->Text = L"On";
```

Looking at the rest of my tasks, getting this right will give me enough clues to attempt them on my own instead of spending ages on endless Google searches.

Comment: `System::Void` ? That's not a C++ type. Are you perhaps using `C++/CX` or one of Microsofts other almost-C++ languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your variable state after toggling the text

```
  static bool isOn = true;
  if(isOn == false)
  {
     toggleButtonText->Text = "Off";
  }
  else
  {
     toggleButtonText->Text = "On";
  }
  isOn = !isOn; //toggle the flag too
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, on one try I had isOn reset to false in the (isOn == false) loop and vice versa for the other loop. Totally understand the answer :).

Answer (score 3):

You need t toggle the flag each time you click the button. You can also greatly reduce the size of your code if you use the `?:` operator:

```
static bool isOn = true;
toggleButtonText->Text = isOn ? "On" : "Off";
isOn = !isOn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using static variable here is an extremely crappy solution. For example, if you change button's state programmatically the static variable will be out of sync with the actual press state.

Why not get toggle state from the button itself? [Here's anwser how to add actual toggle button in the Windows Forms.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776945/461632) After that you can modify the method the following way:

```
System::Void toggleButtonText_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    CheckBox^ button = (CheckBox^)sender;
    if (button->Checked)
    {
        button->Text = "On";
    }
    else
    {
        button->Text = "Off";
    }
}
```