# In VB.Net, when using a CheckBox with a Button appearance, how can you truly center-align the text?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, text, checkbox

I'm using three CheckBoxes in a VB.Net program that are designed to look like Buttons.  I want to center-align the text on these CheckBoxes, so that it is always perfectly in the center of the CheckBox.  So I tried setting the TextAlign property to MiddleCenter, but that didn't exactly work:

[image]

These are not truly center-aligned; they're basically right-aligned against some sort of invisible wall that's close to the center.  Messing with the CheckAlign property doesn't seem to have any impact.  It may be worth mentioning that those five buttons above are actually RadioButtons, and they didn't have this problem.

How can this issue be corrected?  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you making checkboxes look like buttons? Why not using buttons directly? Is this just to have a "checked" property?

Comment: Well, I had originally envisioned the three buttons below each having to be clicked once to be put into its down state, and then clicked a second time to be brought back into its up state, with all three doing this independently of each other.  It was the same idea for the five above, except that they would behave more like RadioButtons.  One thing I noticed though is that selecting either type of fake button actually highlights it, as opposed to keeping it in a down state.

Comment: You are right, they look different when clicked. On the other hand, relying on "fake things" usually provokes problems (it seems from the answer you have got that there are alternatives). Sorry, I cannot be of help on the alignment issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm looking into alternatives now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

Make them actual buttons and toggle the text from "Show XYZ" to "Hide XYZ" when the user clicks the button, that way you will actually have proper buttons that will center correctly for you.

Alternatively, consider making a `ToolStripButton` hosted inside of a `ToolStipContainer` to create a toggle button effect, which could nicely be displayed above the results of the `Load` button. Read the answers for [ToggleButton in C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms).