# How can I disable button press?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make some controls just for their view. For example I need a button which remains unpressed when it's pressed, like it seems on visual basic editor. How can I make this button?

Edit: Here is what I want

Before press:

[image]

After press:

[image]

Comment: Any button remains unpressed after it's pressed. It only goes into "pressed" state for the moment between mouse down and mouse up. Please add a screenshot to clarify your issue.

Comment: what does `remains unpressed when it's pressed` mean?  are you talking about the action or the way it changes appearance as it is pressed?

Comment: thanks for the answers. I need a button for it's display not for any actions. sorry for my English.

Comment: then put an image of a button on PictureBox so you can totally confuse the user.

Comment: are you now saying you want the sizing handles to appear?  How is that "just for their view" - it begs for user interaction.

Comment: I've fixed sizing issue and ignored a square around the button. I just want it not to press. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20716/Allow-the-User-to-Resize-Controls-at-Runtime

Comment: Do you want it to fire events still? Just change the visual appearance?

Comment: yes, I want it to fire events like resizing, dragging dropping

Comment: Then use @DavidSdot's answer, option #3 - make an image of a button and place it on your form as a picturebox control (or make a custom control that would do the same).

Comment: but borders would be a problem after resize?

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. Then do custom drawing - http://stackoverflow.com/a/416529/897326. Also check this out - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315013/WinForms-Button (a custom button control), unless you need a standard button there.

Comment: You decided to go with custom drawing?

Comment: yes, I decided to go with custom drawing

Answer (score 1):

Just a few possibilites

1. WinForms: yourButton.Enabled = false
2. WPF: yourButton.IsHitTextVisible = false
3. Make a image of a button and place it in your form