# Is there any way to create a 3D button in Windows forms using VC++?

Tags: forms, visual-c++

Is there any way to create a 3D button in Windows forms using VC++?
This button would be something like the following:
1. When you do not push it, it pops up.
2. When you push it, it becomes flat.

Thanks

Comment: So... a standard Windows button then? `System.Windows.Forms.Button`?

Comment: I tried that standard button with pop up style. But that is not the one I want.

Comment: I think my question is how to modify that standard button to be a 3D button.

Comment: [ToggleButton in C# WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms)