# Buttons in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently working on some software in Windows Forms and I was wondering if there's any way to have the buttons stay in their "clicked" state? I want to use them like radio buttons so one would be "clicked" and the other normal, and will switch when the other is selected.

I've looked in the Button properties but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Does WinForms not have radio buttons? I seem to remember it does...

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms/3776945#3776945) to a would-be duplicate.  I searched for "toggle button"

Comment: As said by @ryanyuyu use a [RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with it's [Appearance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to Button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make checkbox or radiobutton look like a [Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
cb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```