# on off button stays at On

Tags: c#, button

I want to create a toggle button but it stays at On. How do I toggle the button from on to off.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Location = new Point(200, 30);
    button.Text = "Off";
    this.Controls.Add(button);

    if (button.Text != "On")
    {
        button.Text = "On";
        button.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (button.Text == "On")
    {
        button.Text = "On";
        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the code to change the button's appearance in the `Click` event handler of that button:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Location = new Point(200, 30);
    button.Text = "Off";
    this.Controls.Add(button);

    // subscribe to the Click event
    button.Click += button_Click;
}

// the Click handler
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;

    if (button.Text != "On")
    {
        button.Text = "On";
        button.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (button.Text == "On")
    {
        button.Text = "Off";
        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

And note that in your `else` block you set the **wrong text**. Change it to `"Off"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are always setting the text to `On`. Change your else block:

```
else if (button.Text == "On")
{
    button.Text = "Off"; // here !!!
    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Or use this solution to create a ToggleButton:
[ToggleButton in C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: I've changed it to ""off"" still stays at On.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this: *creation* + *changing* state on click:

```
  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
    // Initial creation
    Button button = new Button() {
      Location = new Point(200, 30),
      Text = "Off",
      BackColor = Color.Red,  
      Parent = this,
    };

    // Click handle, let it be lambda
    // Toggle on click (when clicked change On -> Off -> On ...)
    button.Click += (s, ev) => {
      Button b = sender as Button;

      if (b.Text == "On") {
        // when "On" change to "Off"
        b.Text = "Off";
        b.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
      else {
        b.Text = "On";
        b.BackColor = Color.Green;
      } 
    };
  }
```