# C# winforms button with solid border, like 3d

Tags: c#, winforms, button

How can I create button with solid border(3d), like picture below on C# winforms?

[image: 3d-button]

Panel `BorderStyle` can be set as `Fixed3D`, but buttons `BorderStyle` cannot be set as `Fixed3D`.

I also already  tried `FlatAppearance` which is actualy flat style.

Comment: Pls put questions after doing some research. This is a pretty easy question and would be easily available if efforts are put. Anyways the answer is set  BorderStyle as Fixed3D.

Comment: FlatAppearance= Popup will help you I think

Comment: Panel BorderStyle can be set as Fixed3D, but buttons BorderStyle cannot be set as Fixed3D.
FlatAppearance is actualy FlatStyle and I already tried this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can customize the `Button` control this way have thick 3d borders:

- Set the Button `FlatStyle` to be `Flat`
- In the `FlatApperanace` set `BorderSize` to `0`
- In the `FlatApperanace` set `MouseOverBackColor` to `ControlLight`

Then handle `Paint` event and using [`ControlPaint.DrawBorder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ControlPaint_DrawBorder_System_Drawing_Graphics_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_System_Drawing_Color_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBorderStyle_) draw a thick 3d border:

```
private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, button1.ClientRectangle,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
        SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I tried to override OnPaint, but the result was awful. Your solution is perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. I also prefer deriving from `Button` and overriding `OnPaint` specially if you want to make it a reusable control.

Comment: When I use this ControlPaint.DrawBorder approach on a button that I have set the Fore/Back colors on, it works well until I move the mouse into the button. Then, the background color changes back to a light color.  Is this DrawBorder call redrawing everything inside the rectangle and thus overriding the BackColor with the ControlLightLight color?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Reza's post (thanks Reza!) ... you could get a bit fancier and invert the 3D effect when the button is down:

```
    private bool blnButtonDown = false;

    private void button_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (blnButtonDown == false)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button).ClientRectangle,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Outset);
        }
        else
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button).ClientRectangle,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);
        }
    }

    private void button_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        blnButtonDown = true;
        (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button).Invalidate();
    }

    private void button_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        blnButtonDown = false;
        (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button).Invalidate();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about how thick the border is, you can use the following code.
(I choose my checkbox' appearance as button, and I like it raised when not checked and sunken when checked)

```
private void checkbox_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox myCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
            Rectangle borderRectangle = myCheckbox.ClientRectangle;
            if (myCheckbox.Checked)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
                    Border3DStyle.Sunken);
            }
            else
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
                    Border3DStyle.Raised);
            }
        }
```

Just in case you don't know how to use this code: All you need to do is choose your button/checkbox in your designer, then go to the Properties window and choose the Events tab (click the Thunderbolt). Find the event called Paint and type your event handler's name without the parenthesis in box next to it (such as checkbox_paint).  In the code window that pops up afterwards fill in your code.  Then you are all set.