# Overriding default WinForm button appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to change button appearance by inheriting buttonbase then overriding it's OnPaint method.
[image]
However it still has unwanted, black rectangle over it as seen here:

Thank in advance for any tips (code can be seen on the image aswell).

Comment: What should be the appereance? Not filled with a black border or what?

Comment: Instead of screenshot of code, post the code, then someone can copy the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Start with `Button` as base class. Call `base.OnPaint(e)` in `OnPaint` override or draw with your custom logic. Currently you didn't provide any painting logic for the control and you see the result.

Comment: Here is an example: [C# winforms button with solid border, like 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484556/c-sharp-winforms-button-with-solid-border-like-3d). In the example I used `Paint` event for an existing `Button`. You can override the `OnPaint` method when creating an inherited `Button`