# Is it possible to take control on button paint process in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm want to paint button myself.
Can i do this using only standard .NET classes(not winapi imports)?

Comment: Yes It's possible. What's your requirement exactly?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, i need to change default color and make button more flat(such as in vgui and all source games).

Comment: For such requirement you don't need custom painting. For example you can set `FlatStyle` to `Flat`.

Comment: And for making buttons like this?
[link](https://www.google.ru/search?q=vgui&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&imgil=VyMgIKQNMn7gcM%253A%253BuGU6l_o2UgYrwM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fdeveloper.valvesoftware.com%25252Fwiki%25252FHammer_General_Options&source=iu&pf=m&fir=VyMgIKQNMn7gcM%253A%252CuGU6l_o2UgYrwM%252C_&usg=__DAa5dYbCUxssOPR-rZlBqlvCQtY%3D&biw=1440&bih=794&ved=0ahUKEwjDjMjil-7QAhUUOVAKHXtIBl0QyjcIQw&ei=61hOWIPrKJTywAL7kJnoBQ#imgrc=VyMgIKQNMn7gcM%3A)
It's flat and 3d. Or 3d and flat.

Comment: You can Paint button yourself, take a look at [Animated Glow Effect for Button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049068/3110834) or [3d Button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37485355/3110834) or many other custom painting examples.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, nice, it's works. Big thanks. But in theory i can repaint ANY control?

Comment: Yes, and you can use 
[Control.Draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/464fk752(v=vs.110).aspx "MSDN").

Comment: What about second border on focus?

Comment: this should be what are you looking for 
[MSDN FlatAppearance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatappearance(v=vs.110).aspx "MSDN FlatAppearance")

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are two ways to ways to change button style and color. The second one is only for **Visual Studio** Only (in my opinion).

1). **Changing Button Properties from Code**

You can Simply access button Properties from the code too. The simple example below implements this.

```
            Button SButton = new Button();

            SButton.Location = new Point(120, 90);
            SButton.Size = new Size(70, 35);
            SButton.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            SButton.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            SButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            SButton.Text = "Click Me";
            SButton.Visible = true;

            this.Controls.Add(SButton as Control);
```

2). **Changing Button Style, Colors and Font using Designer ** (using Visual Studio)

Just Click on the button in designer , goto Properties and change **Flat Style** to `Flat` (or choose any other according to your desire) , then choose **BackColor** and **ForeColor** from Properties. Similarly, you can also choose different `Font` in the **Font** property of the button and So on.

Comment: I mean take full control on rendering process, not simply change colors.