# Vb. net button second click

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

On first click I'd like to see listbox and some buttons disabled.
On second click I'd like to see that listbox and buttons enabled again.

My current code is:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Button2.Click
    lstbx_1.Enabled = False
    lstbx_2.Enabled = False
    outbtn.Enabled = False
    Button2.Text = "remove approval"
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  IS there a problem?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: sounds like a ToggleButton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: @Plutonix – I tried to think about the merit of the question and edited it for higher clarity. Hopefully I got it right.

Comment: I deleted the answer until the you clarify what exactly you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        lstbx_1.Enabled = Not (lstbx_1.Enabled)
        lstbx_2.Enabled = Not (lstbx_2.Enabled)
        outbtn.Enabled = Not (outbtn.Enabled)

        If lstbx_1.Enabled = False Then
            Button2.Text = "remove approval"
        Else
            Button2.Text = "Your Text"
        End If

    End Sub
```