# Double press of a button c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am struggling to make a button to be pressed multiple times with different outcomes. I have a few buttons to add some strings to a list. The problem is that I want to press the button to add an item and, if I press it again, to delete the same item.

```
private void labelPineapple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(pineapple))
     {
         My_Pizza.Items.Add(pineapple);
         labelPineapple.BackColor = Color.Green;
     }
}
```

Comment: What about `My_Pizza.Items.Remove(pineapple);` ?

Comment: i just realized that I wasn't using the else statement, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some kind of toggle behavior, we have this "toggle" behavior when the next click "denies" the last one. If I had some more details on if you have a specific button for each item or if you're a selection a item in a list and then pressing the button, I'd be more precise.

If you're selecting an item and then clicking "remove", you can do something like this:

```
private void DeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.SelectedItems.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems);
}
```

If somehow you're using the same button to remove the last value you added, you can use a local variable to store the old value like in:

```
private void labelPineapple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(pineapple))
   {
      My_Pizza.Items.Add(pineapple);
      labelPineapple.BackColor = Color.Green;
      _oldValue = pineapple;
   }
   else
   {
      My_Pizza.Items.Remove(_oldValue);
   }
}
```

If the same button will always and only add/remove the same item, use a [toggle button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776945/6490459) instead.

Sometimes we developers try to solve simple things with harder approaches, when things get too complex, try to write down what you're trying to achieve and the possible solutions.

**Update**: if you have the pineapple object at the moment you're removing it, you don't need to store it as _oldValue. You can remove it directly inside your else statement.

Comment: I've just realized if you have the pineapple object at the moment you're deleting it, you don't need to store it as _oldValue.

Comment: I am quite new to this environment so everything is  kindly welcomed, thank you :D