# C# Multiple Ping start and overlap their Results

Tags: c#, winforms, ping

I have created a code that will continously test the if the connection is available and is supposed to be able to change the IP and always needs to run so it can show in a notificion if the connection is available or not. I can execute it with no errors but when I click the send button again it starts another ping that will also put the results in the label box overlapping each other. I am open to all sugestions to fixing this.

```
    private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //send button
    {
        int unterbrechung = 0;
        await Task.Delay(12);
        //Erstellen Variablen
        string value = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as dynamic).Value;
        double laufzeit = 0;
        double delayins = 0;
        int delay = 1000;
        int onetimebubble = 1; //Zum verhindern von wieder erscheinen der Warnmeldung
        //Zum verhindern das MiniIcon ein weiterers mal zu ändern.
        int onetimeminired = 0; 
        int onetimeminigreen = 0;
        //Ping Variablen deklarieren und setzen
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions
        {
            DontFragment = true
        };
        pingSender.SendAsyncCancel();
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        unterbrechung = 1;
        //Ping senden und bei fehler entsprechende meldung anzeigen
        while (unterbrechung == 1)
        {              
            try
            {
                //Ping ausführen und Ausgabe meldung

                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(value, timeout, buffer, options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    labelOutput.Text = "Address        :" + reply.Address.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                                       "Status         :" + reply.Status + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                                       "Laufzeit in s  :" + laufzeit;
                    labelOutput.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //Reset der Variable
                    if (onetimeminigreen == 0)
                    {
                        //ändern Symbol + vorheriger test
                        minIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Symbol2;
                        onetimeminigreen = 1;
                        onetimeminired = 0;
                    }
                    if (onetimebubble == 0)
                    {
                        onetimebubble = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(PingException)
            {
                //Reset Laufzeit
                laufzeit = 0;
                //ausgabe fehlermeldung
                labelOutput.Text = "Address        :" + value + " " + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Status         :Failed" + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Laufzeit in s  :" + laufzeit;
                labelOutput.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                await Task.Delay(10);
                if (onetimeminired == 0)
                {
                    //ändern Symbol + vorheriger test
                    minIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Symbol1;
                    onetimeminigreen = 0;
                    onetimeminired = 1;
                }
                if (onetimebubble == 1)
                {
                    //ausgabe Warnmeldung + vorheriger test                  
                    minIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                    minIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Ping Failed!";
                    minIcon.BalloonTipText = "Sie haben keine verbindung zu ihrem Host";
                    minIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
                    onetimebubble = 0;                     
                }
            }
            //Ausführen delay
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            //erechnen des Delay in sekunden und laufzeit berechnung
            delayins = delay / 1000;
            laufzeit = laufzeit + delayins;
        }


    }
```

**EDIT** Forgot the Question. How do I change my programm in the way that if I click the button again it cancels all other pings I started before. that "unterbrechung" was something I tried to achieve that but failed.

**Encapsulate pinging**
As Fildor suggested I added a new class for the Ping that simply returns the result

```
    public bool Ping(string ipaddress)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions
        {
            DontFragment = true
        };
        int timeout = 120;
        pingSender.SendAsyncCancel();
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        try
        {
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ipaddress, timeout, buffer, options);
            if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**METHOD PING AND UI CHANGES** As Fildor also suggested I now added a method that will execute the ping and also the change the UI according to the Pings Result

```
    private void ExecPingAndChangeUI()
    {
        runtime = 0; //reset runtime
        delayins = interval / 1000; // umwandeln in Sekunden
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) //Überprüfen ob ein Element in der Combobox ausgewählt wurde
        {
            value = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as dynamic).Value; //Auslesen der Combobox
            status = Ping(value); //Auslesen des Ping ergebnisses

            if (status == true)
            {
                //Ausgabe an OutputLabel
                labelOutput.Text = "Address      : " + Environment.NewLine + value + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Status       : " + Environment.NewLine + "Success" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Laufzeit in s: " + Environment.NewLine + runtime + "s";
                labelOutput.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                if (minIcon.Icon != Properties.Resources.Symbol2)  //ändern Symbol + Test ob symbol schon das ausgewählte ist
                {
                    minIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Symbol2;
                }

                if (onetimebubble == false)
                {
                    onetimebubble = true;
                }

                runtime = runtime + delayins; //laufzeit berechnung
            }
            else if (status == false)
            {
                runtime = 0; //Reset Laufzeit     
                //Ausgabe an OutputLabel
                labelOutput.Text = "Address      : " + Environment.NewLine + value + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Status       : " + Environment.NewLine + "Failed" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                   "Laufzeit in s: " + Environment.NewLine + runtime + "s";
                labelOutput.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                if (minIcon.Icon != Properties.Resources.Symbol1) //ändern Symbol + vorheriger test
                {
                    minIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Symbol1;
                }

                if (onetimebubble == true) //ausgabe Warnmeldung + vorheriger test 
                {
                    minIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
                    onetimebubble = false;
                }
                runtime = runtime + delayins; //laufzeit berechnung
            }
        }
        else
        {
            labelOutput.Text = "Bitte ein Element auswählen!"; //falls nichts in der Combobox ausgewählt wurde
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing all that in the event handler. You could use a Timer for example. As is, the behavior you describe is totally expected.

Comment: If your only concern is to be able to change the IP "on-the-fly" then get the `value` inside the while loop. Then you don't even need to click again. If you do that I'd even disable the button for as long as the ping shall run. But I recommend refactoring nonetheless.

Comment: @Fildor could you give me an example how I could use a Timer to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend a "little" refactoring of that code:

### Encapsulate pinging

Write a class that has only one purpose: Send a ping and return the result.
If the Ping class is a high enough abstraction for you, I would make an instance a private class property, that will be configured by the method of point 1 in next paragraph.

### Introduce a Timer

Since you want to do recurring ping, it seems reasonable to use a Timer for that. This implies following steps:

1. Have a method that uses above mentioned ping class to execute the ping and updates the UI according to the delivered result. It should gather all needed information to execute the ping ( target, data ... ) so you can change ping target on the fly and it will be reflected accordingly when the next tick fires.
2. Change the contents of the button_click handler and the containing class as such:

   2.1. have a property of type Timer. (default = null)

   2.2. on button click:

   2.2.1. check if timer property is not null:
             True - stop timer and null property ( = stop pinging ),
             False - go on

   2.2.2. Create a Timer , set timer property to reference that and start it. The timer's tick shall execute the method of point 1.

### Remarks

You may want to have a second button to explicitly stop pinging without starting a new ping. Hint: You could use a [ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776945/982149) and use its state information to decide whether to start or stop pinging.

Note: The timer may execute it's tick handler (method from point 1.) on a separate thread depending on what timer implementation you use. So you may need to marshal UI-Updates to the UI thread. There are several possible methods to do that. I advise you to do the research yourself, as you stated you are a novice coder. You will learn *a lot* in the course.

Also, you may want to make sure that when the timer fires a tick, the last ping has returned (so they won't overlap).

Note: In order to improve this answer, I will add some references for you to start with later, when I'm at home.

Timer: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx (Code example inside)

Comment: added Method for executing the Ping and changing the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line of code at the beginning and at the end of your method to enable/disable

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;

    ....
    ....
    ....

    Button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

This should work fine with async/await.

Comment: This will only enforce setting `unterbechung` to something != 1 before you can click again. It won't improve the overall suboptimal design.

Comment: @Fildor : Your are right, I wanted to stick to the original request, I did not notice the infinite loop ^^ (and yes, a refactoring is welcome to a more efficient solution)

Comment: Yea I'm amateur in programming first time I actually wrote a programm in c#