# How can I create a toggle button in Visual Studio with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

Is there a way to create a toggle button in C# windows forms? I want to have is as such that when you toggle the button, the background changes from red to transparent. I've done that with a button but it would be better with toggle. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms
In general in winforms, if you need any special look that not supported directly you will need to implement your own drawing of the control.

Comment: Yes there is. But we need first to see your way or any effort in code trying to achieve that.

Comment: Please try to find a library where toggle button implemented and let us know if you have problems

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, you want the background to change from red to transparent when you switch buttons.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = true;

        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
                this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
        }
```

Result:

[image]