# Show panel on click

Tags: c#, webforms, panel

please for a little help in displaying the panel at the click of a button, namely in my application I have a FormMenu in which the panelCentralForm is displayed when loading.

When I click on btnListOfActiveUser_Click I manage to open FormListStaff over panelCentralForm using this code:

```
 private void btnListOfActiveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormListStaff formListStaff = new FormListStaff();
            AddFormToPanel(formListStaff);
        }

 private void AddFormToPanel(object form)
        {
            if (this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Count > 0)
                this.panelCentralForm.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            Form fh = form as Form;
            fh.TopLevel = false;
            fh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Add(fh);
            this.panelCentralForm.Tag = fh;
            fh.Show();
        }
```

my question is how can I in a similar way that now when I click on buttonDashboard to return to me the first view, ie the view from the Central Form panel (panelCentralForm).

```
   private void buttonDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelCentralForm.Visible = true; //something like this, p.s. this code doesn't just work as an example I wrote
        }
```

[the whole view belongs from FormMenu.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FteDV.png)

Thanks a lot to everyone for the help

Comment: Sounds like you want a toggle button? If so check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282118/togglebutton-in-c-sharp-winforms) you can use a checkbox then set the appearance to button. Depending on the state of the check box you can then either show or hide the FormListStaff

Comment: @Anonymous ok thanks for the reply, do you have any example?

Comment: You could save the Form fh globally and then use fh.Hide() in your buttonDashboard_Click() method.

Comment: @ValentinSky thanks for the comment but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how can I in a similar way that now when I click on
>   buttonDashboard to return to me the first view

Just [Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear?view=netcore-3.1) the panel, then add the label back in?

```
this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Clear();
this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Add(label1);
```

The label should still be accessible even though it was previously removed from the panel since it is declared at form level in your designer file.

Comment: It's unclear where "buttonDashboard" resides, though.  Is it in the same place as "btnListOfActiveUser", or is it in the child form "FormListStaff"?

Comment: I corrected the question, I added the layout of FormMenu, and from which I open FormListStaff on the left side to btnListOfActiveUser_Click ()
I just need more for Dashboard to return me to the initial state with panelCentralForm and label1 content, thank you very much for your effort and help

Comment: great, it only works, it shows me more label1 all the way to the corner, can I set its location as it is current in menuForm? LIKE:
this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Clear();
label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
label1.Location = new Point(28, 39); //it doesn't work for me, where am I wrong?
this.panelCentralForm.Controls.Add(label1);

Comment: If you don't want it to fill the entire panel then remove the `Dock` line.